# golang map not adding element

Tags: go, go-map

There is battleFoundmap in my code and i tried the add a element like this:(battle is not nil)

```
battleFoundMap[battle.ID] = battle.Answers
```

But when i debug it it returns 1:27: expected '==', found '=' error and not put in it. How to solve it?

Here is map and Card struct

```
var battleFoundMap map[uint][]models.Card

type Card struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId             uint      `json:"userid"`
    Name               string    `json:"name"`
    Meaning            string    `json:"meaning"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise a map with make before using it.

change

```
var battleFoundMap map[uint][]models.Card
```

to

```
battleFoundMap := make(map[uint][]models.Card)
```

That should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ShivaKishore's answer,

When you declare a map like, `var name map[KeyType]ValueType`. The value of this map is `nil` and has a length of `0`.

A `nil` map has no key-values nor can be added. It behaves like an empty map for read-operations but causes a runtime panic if you want to write data to it.

```
var m map[string]string

// reading
m["foo"] == "" // works.

// writing
m["foo"] = "bar" // will panic.
```

But, initializing a map with `make` creates an empty map that works with both read and write operations.

```golang
// as you can't declare a map globally using shorthands
var m map[string]string
m = make(map[string]string)
```

or, using shorthands

```
m := make(map[string]string)
```